# How to reuse captured block in Slim and avoid duplicates?

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

Look at this code snippet:

```rb
require 'slim'

SLIM = <<-SLIM
    - column do
        = 'Text '
SLIM

def column(&block)
    $column = block
end

#########

template = Slim::Template::new { SLIM }
template.render(self)


p $column.call
p $column.call
p $column.call
```

As you can see I have captured block (it render 'Text ' string) to `$column` global variable and call it 3 times. I expect that will be printed:

```
"Text "
"Text "
"Text "
```

but instead I see:

```
"Text "
"Text Text "
"Text Text Text "
```

How to capture block and avoid duplicates?

Comment: It looks like you went into recursive calls there. I have no idea about `SLIM`, but should not there `column do` block **be terminated with corresponding `end`**?

Comment: @mudasobwa - That’s SLIM (http://slim-lang.com) no need to close a block

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are passing block with `= 'Text '` value, and `=` in `Slim` is accumulating values, that's why you get incremented string

Why you can't just call `template.render(self)` multiple times?

```
require 'slim'

SLIM = <<-SLIM
    - column do
        = 'Text '
SLIM

def column(&block)
  block.call
end

#########

template = Slim::Template::new { SLIM }
p template.render(self)
p template.render(self)
p template.render(self)
```

Comment: The `column` method is part of helper to render table. So, I want to capture block for render column once and call it multiple times (for all rows in table). For this reason I don't want to call `render` method multiple times.

Comment: but for each row you should have different data, you should pass this context in render method and call render multiple times. Or alternatively use  `each` block.

Comment: Yes, pass the row context to captured block is not a problem: `CustomScope.new(self, row_index).instance_eval(&column.block).html_safe` but execution of `instance_eval` cause problem with duplicates described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try `p #{yield}` directly 3 times if ypu are using slim without framework.